PDE $\sum \frac{dy}{dx_n} x_n$
Let $y=f(\vec{x})$ be a multivariable function where the elements of $\vec{x}$ are indexed by $n \in [1,N]$. I want to understand what form the solution to the following PDE should take:
$$y (\vec{x}) = \sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_n} x_n \right)$$
Could you kindly advise what conditions the solution should satisfy? I do not have boundary conditions to pin down a particular solution, and I would like to understand the general requirements for an acceptable solution.
Example:
Let $N=2$ for simplicity. We can verify that $y=x_1 + x_2$ is a solution because it satisfies the PDE:
\begin{align}
x_1 + x_2 &= \sum_{n=1}^2 \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_n} x_n \right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} (x_1 + x_2) x_1 + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} (x_1 + x_2) x_2 \\
&= x_1 + x_2 \\
\end{align}
But $y=x_1^{\frac{1}{2}} x_2^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is also a solution because:
\begin{align}
x_1^{\frac{1}{2}} x_2^{\frac{1}{2}} &= \sum_{n=1}^2 \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_n} x_n \right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \left(x_1^{\frac{1}{2}} x_2^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) x_1 + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} \left(x_1^{\frac{1}{2}} x_2^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) x_2 \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2} x_1^{-\frac{1}{2}} x_2^{\frac{1}{2}} x_1\right) + \left(x_1^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{2} x_2^{-\frac{1}{2}} x_2\right) \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2} x_1^{\frac{1}{2}} x_2^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) + \left(x_1^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{2} x_2^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(x_1^{\frac{1}{2}} x_2^{\frac{1}{2}} + x_1^{\frac{1}{2}} x_2^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(2 x_1^{\frac{1}{2}} x_2^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) \\
&= x_1^{\frac{1}{2}} x_2^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
\end{align}
What do these solutions have in common?

No boundary conditions? One solution is $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i$.

No boundary conditions. This works thanks.

$\displaystyle{{\rm d} \over {\rm d}x_{n}}$  must be $\displaystyle{\partial \over \partial x_{n}}$.

Fixed thank you.

Not sure why the downvotes here, this is indeed a well known DE which, thanks to Euler, is associated with the requirement of $y$ being positive homogeneous of degree $1$. You can look up Euler's homogenous function theorem, but the proof goes something as follows:
H(1)$\rightarrow$ your PDE: take the general definition of homogeneity of degree $k$, and use the chain rule to differentiate both sides, then take the limit for $k\rightarrow1$
your PDE $\rightarrow$ H(1): define $z(k):=f(kx)$, then the condition implies $kz'(k)=Nz(k)$ whose solutions require homogeneity in $f$

Separation of variables would give a solution
$$
y = \prod_{n=1}^N x_n^{\alpha_n}
$$
for any $\{\alpha_n\}$ where $\sum_{n=1}^N\alpha_n = 1$, or any linear combination of such solutions.  Although I agree it is hard to see whether such solutions are useful without boundary conditions.
